# Can't run an android project

Tags: android, ide

I have been given a source program for android game and i as usual imported it to android studio but didn't work out as there was C++ files inside.
here is a pic of the source code files

[image: Image link]

There are also " Cocos2d-x " library files inside.
How can i run such this source code.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I run it using eclipse with android SDK although it has been stopped by android developers.

Answer (score 1):

I think that's because it isn't built with Android Studio. It's built with something called Cocos Creator.

According to their website, 
*Cocos Creator is a unified package of game development tools. Starting with the workflow, it also includes a game engine (based on Cocos2d-x), resource management, scene editing, game previewing, debugging and publishing your project to multiple platforms.*

Run it in this and it'll open. 
http://www.cocos2d-x.org/